# Python sorting in @property

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class SortingQueue:
    _queue = []

    @property
    def queue(self):
        sorted(self._queue, key=attrgetter("votes"), reverse=True)
        return self._queue
```

I have this code, but when i reference to queue in this class i get an unsorted version. Sorting it outside of the function works. Is there any limitation that you cant use `@property` in this case?

We need this as we are going to change the values in `_queue` that will change the sort order on output.

Comment: This sorts the list everytime you access the list, which I think is unexpected for attribute access. If you access the property a lot I would recommend some kind of caching, e.g. a `_is_sorted` flag that is set to false when something gets changed/added to the list and the @property only sorts when `_is_sorted` is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sorted()` returns a newly sorted list while leaving `self._queue` untouched.
In order to make your code work the way you expected you should call the method `.sort()`

```
class SortingQueue:
    _queue = []

    @property
    def queue(self):
        self._queue.sort(key=attrgetter("votes"), reverse=True)
        return self._queue
```

The other way to fix it using `sorted()` is this:

```
class SortingQueue:
    _queue = []

    @property
    def queue(self):
        self._queue = sorted(self._queue, key=attrgetter("votes"), reverse=True)
        return self._queue
```

edit: In my haste I overlooked the fact this was a @property.  I would normally suggest not letting a property alter 'hidden attribute _queue'.  In which case I would do something like this:

```
class SortingQueue:
    _queue = []

    @property
    def queue(self):
        return sorted(self._queue, key=attrgetter("votes"), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function `sorted` doesn't sort in-place. It returns a sorted list. `self._queue.sort` will sort in-place. Depending on what you want, you can either sort your list, or just put `return sorted(...)`.